# How do I set max size for image in javascript(hover)

Tags: javascript

I'm using this script:

```
    <html>
<script>
    function hover(element) {
  element.setAttribute('src', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff');
}

function unhover(element) {
  element.setAttribute('src', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff');
}
</script>
<img id="my-img" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" onmouseover="hover(this);" onmouseout="unhover(this);" />
</html>
```

I will change the image source but I want to fix width to 120px. How can I do this?

Comment: Can be done with simple css. WHat have you tried and what research have you done on this issue?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

Using the style attribute

`element.style.width = '120px';`

and you can also add alot more styling with the same attribute like padding, margin, font-size, ..etc

Comment: YOUR AWESOME SERIOUSLY